# Sum of specific rows in a dataframe (Pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm given a set of the following data:

```
week  A      B      C      D      E
1     243    857    393    621    194
2     644    576    534    792    207
3     946    252    453    547    436
4     560    100    864    663    949
5     712    734    308    385    303
```

I’m asked to find the sum of each column **for specified rows/a specified number of weeks**, and then plot those numbers onto a bar chart to compare A-E.

Assuming I have the rows I need (e.g. `df.iloc[2:4,:]`), what should I do next? My assumption is that I need to create a mask with a single row that includes the sum of each column, but I'm not sure how I go about doing that.

I know how to do the final step (i.e. `.plot(kind='bar'`), I just need to know what the middle step is to obtain the sums I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use for select by positions `iloc`, `sum` and [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
df.iloc[2:4].sum().plot.bar()
```

[image: graph1]

Or if want select by names of index (here weeks) use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[2:4].sum().plot.bar()
```

[image: graph2]

Difference is `iloc` exclude last position:

```
print (df.loc[2:4])
        A    B    C    D    E
week                         
2     644  576  534  792  207
3     946  252  453  547  436
4     560  100  864  663  949

print (df.iloc[2:4])
        A    B    C    D    E
week                         
3     946  252  453  547  436
4     560  100  864  663  949
```

---

And if need also filter columns by positions:

```
df.iloc[2:4, :4].sum().plot.bar()
```

And by names (weeks):

```
df.loc[2:4, list('ABCD')].sum().plot.bar()
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is call `.sum()` on your subset of the data:

```
df.iloc[2:4,:].sum()
```

Returns:

```
week       7
A       1506
B        352
C       1317
D       1210
E       1385
dtype: int64
```

Furthermore, for plotting, I think you can probably get rid of the `week` column (as the sum of week numbers is unlikely to mean anything):

```
df.iloc[2:4,1:].sum().plot(kind='bar')
# or
df[list('ABCDE')].iloc[2:4].sum().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: plot]